# Creating Charts in PHP

Tags: php, charts

I would like to create a simple Chart in PHP. It should show a temperature value over time. Is there any simple library you can recommand?

Regards

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personal use [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/) - it is free and very powerful. The rendered graphic looks very nice.

You can download it [here](http://jpgraph.net/download/).

Comment: I downloaded JpGraph and set up an example. But is says: Use the GD version that comes wthh PHP and not the standalone version. I installed GD like this: apt-get install php5-gd

Comment: @Florian Yes, this has to be installed - it was already in my PHP version [I compile it on my own]. But then it works like a charm.

Comment: I installed it, but it seems to be the wrong version. Is there an easier way than compiling PHP myself?

Comment: @Florian my GD version is 2.1.0 and PHP 5.6.19. Compiling PHP may be for the first time hard but you can use any module you want to.

Comment: I very much agree with this - it doesn't rely on external server which is very important for me - also combine this with PHPExcel and you can have the users define the graphs in excel and use php to add the data and then these created that way too

Comment: Why doesn't it work with the package I installed?

Comment: @Florian what does "it doesn't work" mean? Any errors, messages, exceptions, ...?

Comment: When I try to create a graph, it shows an error: JpGraph Error: 25128 The function imageantialias() is not available in your PHP installation. Use the GD version that comes with PHP and not the standalone version.

Comment: @Florian The 1st Google hit for the error message leads to [this](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/drawing-graphs-in-php-with-jpgraph/) - There is a work around for this error. Did you try it?

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think of searching for the JpGraph error.